# How to get nested tables' data using Eloquent Relationships - Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've two tables: 1. categories, 2. Items

Categories.php

```
____________
id | name
___|________
 1 | shirt
 2 | shoes
```

Items.php

```
__________________________
id | categories_id | name
___|_______________|______
 1 |   1           | casual
 2 |   1           | dress
 3 |   2           | leather
 4 |   2           | jogar
```

Now I want to get the data of both tables using Eloquent relationship.

**Desired array:**

```
[
  'name' => 'shirts',
  'items' => ['casual', 'dress']
],
[
   'name' => 'shoes',
   'items' => ['leather', 'jogar']
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to define your relationship.

By the look of your db structure, it seems that a `Category` has many `Items`. So in this case it can be a [One-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) or [Many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship. I'll go for the first one in this answer.

Now, in your models, define the relationship.

**Category.php**

```php
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
}
```

**Items.php**

```php
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Now, when querying results, you can do as simple use the `with()` method to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationship items

```php
// Perform your query and load the relationship
$categories = Category::with('items')->get();
```

or the `load()` one, to [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) the related items.

```php
// Perform your query
$categories = Category::all();
// load the related items
$categories->load('items');
```

Comment: Thanks, its working. Actually I'm new on laravel and also on ORM.

Comment: @Zia Hi, if this was helpful to you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Link to the documentation: [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships).

in your **Items.php**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories', 'foreign_key');
}
```

From that on just use:

```
$items = new Items;
$category = $items->category;
```

Answer (score 0):

After make model Category and item 
you can go to Category controller and get the data from Category by

```
$cat = Category::all();
```

don not forget add

```
use App\Category;
```

and the same thing if you want Item ,
Best Regards